# find the speaker type from a conversation

Tags: text-generation

I have a data frame in Python with two columns:

```
speaker, text
1, 'Can I ask what is your experience'
2, 'I am John and I have worked in IT for several years and I am proficient in SQL'
2, 'What is SQL injection'
1, 'It is a way to inject unwanted SQL code into a SQL command'
```

I want to find which speaker is an expert and which speaker is not an expert.

Which type of AI models can I use for this purpose? I tried text-generation AI models such as OLMo 7B but I could not find a suitable prompt for it to give me the answer. I sent it to chatGPT and it gives me information about the speaker correctly, but how can I do it offline using open-source AI models and use python programming? I need to change the data frame and replace 1 and 2 with non-expert and expert to identify who is in the conversation.

My question:
1- which AI model can I use for this purpose?
2- What would be my prompt to get a parsable output from the model so I can replace 1 and 2 with suitable text?

Comment: How much data do you have? You could use a simple classifier if you had a ton of data for experts versus non-experts.